# Onsen UI navigation not working after adding tabbar

Tags: onsen-ui

I can't get the navigation to work with the tab bar. I have a list page, search page and details page. For some reason I can't get the list page to persist when navigating either. The details page is never shown even thought I am using `app.navi.pushPage('detail.html')`. Before adding the tab-bar everything worked fine. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

As well, I need to access the detail page from both the list and search pages.

```
<ons-navigator page="list.html" var="app.navi"></ons-navigator>

<ons-tabbar>
    <ons-tab page="favourites.html" label="Favourites" icon="fa-heart"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="list.html" label="Near Me" icon="fa-map-marker" active="true"></ons-tab>      
    <ons-tab page="search.html" label="Search" icon="fa-search"></ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>

<ons-template id="list.html">
    <ons-page id="list-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Near Me</div>
        </ons-toolbar>            
        <ons-list id="lst-estblshmnt"></ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="search.html">
    <ons-page id="search-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Search</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col>
                <input id="srch" type="search" class="search-input">
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col width="75px" style="display: none">
                <ons-button id="btn-cancel-search" modifier="quiet">Cancel</ons-button>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>            
        <ons-list id="lst-srch"></ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="detail.html">
    <ons-page id="detail-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
            <div class="right">
                <ons-toolbar-button id="btn-fllw"><ons-icon icon="fa-heart-o"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col id="establishment-details">
                <header>
                    <center class="item-title">Title</center>
                </header>
                <div class="item-details">
                    <ons-row>
                        <ons-col>
                            <p class="item-address"></p>
                            <p class="item-city"></p>
                            <p class="item-postal_code"></p>
                        </ons-col>                           
                    </ons-row>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row> 
    </ons-list>          

    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot combine `<ons-navigator>` with `<ons-tabbar>`. If you use the tabbar element, you can switch pages using `setActiveTab(index, [options])`. I created a working sample using the template you provided and added a `<ons-button>` in the `list.html` template that changes the active page. For more info about the tabbar element, take a look [here](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-tabbar.html). Let me know if you need more help :)

```html
<body>

    <ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="home"
            label="Home"
            page="list.html"
            active="true"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="comment"
            label="Comments"
            page="search.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="gear"
            label="Settings"
            page="detail.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    </ons-tabbar>
    
    <ons-template id="list.html">
    <ons-page id="list-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Near Me</div>
        </ons-toolbar>            
        <ons-list id="lst-estblshmnt"></ons-list>
        <ons-button id="btn-switch-search"  ng-click="tabbar.setActiveTab(2)">Cancel</ons-button>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="search.html">
    <ons-page id="search-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Search</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col>
                <input id="srch" type="search" class="search-input">
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col width="75px" style="display: none">
                <ons-button id="btn-cancel-search" modifier="quiet">Cancel</ons-button>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row>            
        <ons-list id="lst-srch"></ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="detail.html">
    <ons-page id="detail-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
            <div class="right">
                <ons-toolbar-button id="btn-fllw"><ons-icon icon="fa-heart-o"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-row>
            <ons-col id="establishment-details">
                <header>
                    <center class="item-title">Title</center>
                </header>
                <div class="item-details">
                    <ons-row>
                        <ons-col>
                            <p class="item-address"></p>
                            <p class="item-city"></p>
                            <p class="item-postal_code"></p>
                        </ons-col>                           
                    </ons-row>
                </div>
            </ons-col>
        </ons-row> 
    </ons-list>          

    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

</body>
```

Comment: Many thanks Andi! However, my problem persists since I need to navigate down a hierarchy of child pages from a given tab. For example from the list page a user can navigate to a details page. Is there a way to simply navigate to a page?

Comment: Sorry should have read the docs more fully. I am using loadPage and everything is working as expected.